# How to get Received Signal Strength Indicator (RSSI) of a bluetooth device?

Tags: java, api, bluetooth, rssi

I want to recognize bluetooth device with in my bluetooth device range that means i want to get particular device received signal strength indicator (RSSI).

Is any Java API for getting RSSI of a particular device?

If such exist, please give information about that Java API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a list of Java BlueTooth APIs at [the Wikipedia Article: Java APIs for BlueTooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_APIs_for_Bluetooth).

I'm sure most of them have facilities to read RSSI.

---

I had a look at bluecove.org's API for instance and found this:

- [`RemoteDeviceHelper.readRSSI`](http://snapshot.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/com/intel/bluetooth/RemoteDeviceHelper.html#readRSSI%28javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice%29)

Answer (score -1):

I found this code but I don't know how to get the values , maybe there is a class to be imported:
please  check and let me know.

```
public static int calculateSignalLevel(int rssi, int numLevels) 
 { if (rssi <= MIN_RSSI)     
 {return 0;} else if (rssi >= MAX_RSSI) { return numLevels - 1; } 
 else { int partitionSize 
 = (MAX_RSSI - MIN_RSSI) / (numLevels - 1);  return (rssi - MIN_RSSI) / partitionSize;   }      
 }
```

Comment: This method takes the rssi is an argument, and thus does not answer how to *get hold of it*.